# Правильность js кода

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <button id = "btn2" onclick = "subs(mark1)">City</button>
    <span id = "mark1">London<span id = "mark1s">CITY</span></span>
#mark1{
    border-radius:7px;
    border:0px solid #60C383;
    position:relative;
    padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;
}

    #mark1s{
        width:30px;
        height:12px;
        background-color:#60C383;
        color:black;
        font-size:10px;
        position:absolute;
        left:15px;
        top:18px;
        border-radius:5px;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        display:none;
    }

 

       function subs(string){
            document.getElementById(`${string}`).style.border = "1px solid #60C383"
            document.getElementById(`${string}`"s").style.display  = "flex"
        }

    //вроде проблема в js но в инете мало информации про этой случай, полезного не нашел
```

//проблема была в первой строке html кода нужно было не onclick = "subs(mark1)" а onclick = "subs('mark1')"

Comment: вроде бы да кабы. Вроде сами догадайтесь, что тут у меня вообще не работает, и о чем я спрашиваю. Так что ли? Параметры-строки при вызове функций в кавычке заворачивать начните для начала.

Comment: //вместо js кода ставтье это
  function subs(string){
            document.getElementById('mark1').style.border = "1px solid #60C383"
            document.getElementById('mark1s').style.display  = "flex"
 }
//мне нужно чтобы я не писал много функции с другими именами
// этот код покажет что надо, просто если я буду писать так, то нужно будет много функции вместо одного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function subs(string){
  document.getElementById(`${string}`).style.border = "1px solid #60C383"
  document.getElementById(`${string}s`).style.display  = "flex"
}
```

```css
#mark1{
    border-radius:7px;
    border:0px solid #60C383;
    position:relative;
    padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;
}

#mark1s{
    width:30px;
    height:12px;
    background-color:#60C383;
    color:black;
    font-size:10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    top:18px;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<button id = "btn2" onclick = "subs('mark1')">City</button>
<span id = "mark1">London<span id = "mark1s">CITY</span></span>
```

Comment: тут то что надо, просто незнаю почему у меня показывает ошибку в коде после .style.border-> document.getElementById(`${string}`).style.border = "1px solid #60C383"

Comment: Вы эту строку заменили `<button id = "btn2" onclick = "subs('mark1')">City</button>` ?

Comment: сорян, не на ту кнопку нажал, тут у меня 2 одинаково похожие  кнопки, благодарю за помощ)

Comment: вас не смущает вся эта белиберда вокруг `string` при ее передаче в `getElementById` ?